# Included THEAD and TBODY on this table

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following table that is generated from Sharepoint:

```
<table class="ms-listviewtable">
   <tr>
      <th></th>
   </tr>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
</table>
```

how can I use Jquery to on document load to change the layout of this table to look like

```
  <table class="ms-listviewtable">
  <thead>
   <tr>
      <th></th>
   </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
   <tr>
      <td></td>
   </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Is this table actually completely empty, and containing exactly the HTML you posted, no content and nothing added or removed, with two rows and one column?

Comment: sorry no. this table is full of information but I posted the basical layout for ease of purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi All thanks for everyones contribution to this question. I have managed to get it to work and the throw the tablesorter method around the table.

This is a solution if you ever need to make tablesorter work without the generated table have a THEAD or TBODY tags:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    var $table = $('#ctl00_m_g_fb789c4e_7fc7_47b5_9be4_dfa65d4650e0_ctl00_resultsGrid');

    // This gets the first <tr> within the table, and remembers it here.
    var $headRow = $('tr', $table).first();
    $headRow.remove();

    if (!$table.has('tbody')) {
        var $otherRows = $('tr', $table);
        $otherRows.remove();

        var $tbody = $('<tbody>');
        $table.append($tbody);
        $tbody.append($otherRows);
    }

    var $thead = $('<thead>');
    $table.prepend($thead);
    $thead.append($headRow);

    $("#ctl00_m_g_fb789c4e_7fc7_47b5_9be4_dfa65d4650e0_ctl00_resultsGrid").tablesorter();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

It seems like all modern browsers automatically wrap the contents of a table in a `<tbody>` if you happen to omit the tag, so you'd have to do something like this:

```
$('table').each(function() {
    var $this = $(this);

    $this.children('tbody').children().unwrap();
    $this.children('tr:has(th)').wrapAll('<thead>');
    $this.children('tr:has(td)').wrapAll('<tbody>');
});
```

Test it with older browsers if you want. It seems like it'd work.

Comment: In Google Chrome, all `<tr>` will be child of `<tbody>` automatically (if we don't set). So your code seems not working, check the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hXvss/1/) - note that `<thead>` must be in orange.

Comment: **+1** for creativeness `;)`.

Comment: Removing tbody isn't necessary, since it's not actually there.  Putting it in the desired place doesn't result in an extra set of tbody tags.

Comment: Why base it on whether or not the `tr` has `th` children?  It's perfectly valid for a table to have a row of `th`s to serve as column headers in the `thead`, then have a `th` in each row to serve as row headers.

Comment: @Ghodmode: That's not valid HTML.

Comment: @AndrewBurns: You'll have to be more specific than that. What isn't working? Is the structure turning out the right way?

Comment: I'm wrong.  As @Blender pointed out in my answer below, you do have to remove the `tbody` in order to avoid an extra set of `tbody` tags.

Comment: @Blender ... but I'm right about `th`s being allowed in rows other than the header row.  [The spec](http://developers.whatwg.org/tabular-data.html#the-th-element) even provides examples showing that.

Comment: @blender thanks for your comment. I have now found the solution. Which I have included below.

Comment: @Ghodmode: *Contexts in which this element can be used:
As a child of a tr element.*?

Answer (score 3):

```
var $t = $("table.ms-listviewtable");
if ($t.has("tbody")) $t.find("tbody").children().unwrap();
$t.find("tr:first").wrap("<thead />");
$t.find("tr").not(":first").wrapAll("<tbody />");
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ghodmode/p4pvT/

**Update**: +1 for Blender for pointing out my error.  My original version did in fact create an extra set of `tbody` tags.  The jsFiddle has been updated, too.

Comment: Inspect the `<thead>` element in any modern browser. It's inside of a `<tbody>`.

Answer (score 1):

### Step 1: Store the header row temporarily

First you need to isolate the header and body rows from the DOM, before we rearrange the table's internal layout.

We'll do this using jQuery's [contextual selector](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-selector-context), which you may have seen before. It works by selecting elements *within a context you specify*: if that context is a DOM node - the table, in this case - it selects elements within that DOM node.

**Note:** I use the $ prefix in JavaScript variable names to indicate variables that I'm using to store a jQuery object - which is all of the variables in this exercise. It's a personal convention that you don't have to use yourself.

```
var $table = $('#your-table-id');

// This gets the first <tr> within the table, and remembers it here.
var $headRow = $('tr', $table).first();
$headRow.remove();
```

### Step 2: Create the tbody, if necessary

At this point, our work is either easier or harder. Some browsers, like Firefox, will already have interpreted the the table as having an implicit `<tbody>` element in which all the other rows have already been stored - if that's the case, our job is already done! Otherwise, we have a bit more work to do and need to create that `<tbody>` to store the current rows (all of which are not the header row).

```
if (!$table.has('tbody')) {
    var $otherRows = $('tr', $table);
    $otherRows.remove();

    var $tbody = $('<tbody>');
    $table.append($tbody);
    $tbody.append($otherRows);
}
```

### Step 3: Create the thead

Now we'll insert the thead element at the start of the table, and add our table's header row to it.

```
var $thead = $('<thead>');
$table.prepend($thead);
$thead.append($headRow);
```

Now all is well.

### The code in action, and minus my comments

First: [**JSFiddle demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/6F3MH/)

And now the code without my talking breaking it up:

```
var $table = $('#your-table-id');

// This gets the first <tr> within the table, and remembers it here.
var $headRow = $('tr', $table).first();
$headRow.remove();

if (!$table.has('tbody')) {
    var $otherRows = $('tr', $table);
    $otherRows.remove();

    var $tbody = $('<tbody>');
    $table.append($tbody);
    $tbody.append($otherRows);
}

var $thead = $('<thead>');
$table.prepend($thead);
$thead.append($headRow);
```

### An iterative alternative

This will cover each table with the **ms-listviewtable** class in the document, rather than targeting exactly one table by ID.

```
$('table.ms-listviewtable').each(function() {

    var $table = $(this);

    // The rest of the code as above goes within the function here,
    // except, of course, for the line that sets the $table variable.

});
```

Comment: This is much too easy.  Do you have a version written in assembly? :P

Comment: very detailed solution thank you it helped me.. see below for my final version and my answer thanks!

Comment: @andrewBurns I'm glad it helped you. I just added to the end an alternative method which would iterate over every **ms-listviewtable** (as other answers do, since it's easier). That might work better for your purposes (or it might not).

Answer (score 1):

**[Working jsFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/b8ErE/2/)**

I've used this algorithm, it works for multiple tables, with **multiple rows** for `thead` and `tbody`.

```
$(function () {
    // loop through all tables with specific class
    $('.ms-listviewtable').each(function () {
        var $table = $(this);

        // find all thead rows and save the index
        var thead = [];
        $table.find('tr > th').each(function () {
            var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
            if ($.inArray(index, thead) == -1) {
                thead.push(index);
            }
        });

        // find all tbody rows and save the index
        var tbody = [];
        $table.find('tr > td').each(function () {
            var index = $(this).closest('tr').index();
            if ($.inArray(index, tbody) == -1) {
                tbody.push(index);
            }
        });

        // make tbody and thead tags
        var $tbody = $('<tbody></tbody>');
        var $thead = $('<thead></thead>');

        // insert thead rows from table to new thead element
        $.each(thead, function (i, v) {
            $table.find('tr').eq(v).clone(true).appendTo($thead);
        });     

        // insert tbody rows from table to new tbody element
        $.each(tbody, function (i, v) {
            $table.find('tr').eq(v).clone(true).appendTo($tbody);
        });

        // make table fresh
        $table.html('');
        $thead.appendTo($table);
        $tbody.appendTo($table);
    });
});
```

Comment: Why do you populate the `thead`/`tbody` arrays?

Comment: @Blender Yes, you are right, it's possible to insert the rows inside the `$table.find()` and there is no need to use `thead`/`tbody` arrays, but my first analysis, was: first find the index, then work with them, so, I wrote this code `;)`.

Comment: @Blender However it would be more difficult to write, because it's possible we have multiple columns and rows (as you see, I push the values to the arrays with a condition).

Comment: How would your condition ever be not true?

Comment: @Blender As you see in the code, I loop through the `td` or `th` (not `tr` as I don't want it), so, for each cell I get index of it's parent and push it to the array, for the second and third column the if condition will be false.