# jQuery add thead to the table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `MyFaces Trinidad JSF` framework and it creates tr:table as follows:

```
<table id="myTable">
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I need the below one to implement scrollable header. So I am trying to convert them using `jQuery`

```
<table id="myTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>1</th>
            <th>2</th>
            <th>3</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1</td>
            <td>2</td>
            <td>3</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

I have tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781886/jquery-add-thead-and-add-tbody) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804648/included-thead-and-tbody-on-this-table) answers, but none of them solves my problem.

Comment: Show what you've tried, link to the answers you claim you've tried to use.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12781886/jquery-add-thead-and-add-tbody and this one as well http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16804648/included-thead-and-tbody-on-this-table

Comment: Okay, that's the second part (but it belongs in the question). Show what **you've** tried. In your question.

Comment: Use the "edit" link to improve the question, not comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wrap first row with `thead`  and append at the beginning of the table

```js
$('#myTable tbody tr:first') // get first row
  //.detach() // remove from table, it's optional to detach
  .wrap('<thead/>') // wrap with tbody
  .parent() // get tbody 
  .prependTo('#myTable') // append at the beginning
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">
<tbody>
  <tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
  <tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use

```
// append the first row to thead and prepend thead to #mytable
$('<thead></thead>').append($('tbody > tr:nth-child(1)')).prependTo('#myTable');
// remove the first row from tbody
$('#myTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)').remove();
```

```js
// append the first row to thead and prepend thead to #mytable
$('<thead></thead>').append($('tbody > tr:nth-child(1)')).prependTo('#myTable');
// remove the first row from tbody
$('#myTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)').remove();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="myTable">

<tbody><tr><th>1</th><th>2</th><th>3</th><th>4</th></tr>

<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr>
<tr><td>1</td><td>2</td><td>3</td><td>4</td></tr></tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: I have tried this var myTable = $('table.af_table_content');
 // append the first row to thead and prepend thead to #mytable
 $('<thead></thead>').append($('tbody > tr:nth-child(1)')).prependTo(myTable);
 // remove the first row from tbody
 $('#myTable > tbody > tr:nth-child(1)').remove(); Can you help me in changing the last line? Since there is no id getting generated for that table, trying to use the class attribute

Comment: @Pat : there is no need for that line , since append moving the original tr not copy